# Python - superset of string vs list

Tags: python, set

I have a simple `set` variable named `ss`:

```
ss
Out[5]: {'a', 'ab'}
```

Can someone please explain the following 3 outputs:

```
ss.issuperset('a')
Out[6]: True

ss.issuperset('ab')
Out[7]: False

ss.issuperset(['ab'])
Out[8]: True
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an expansion of the previous answer, for clarity...

`ss.issuperset('ab')` is interpreted as `ss.issuperset(set('ab'))` which might be a little bit confusing, because if you consider the following code:

```
>>> sss = set('ab')
>>> sss
set(['a', 'b'])
```

you will notice that set('ab') is set(['a', 'b']). Now is `ss` a super-set of `set(['a', 'b'])`? no because `ss` does not contain `'b'`, hence the `False`.

The reason why `set('ab')` is interpreted as `set(['a', 'b'])` is that `set()` accepts an *Iterable* object as an argument, `set()` iterates over the passed iterable while adding the elements one after the other. In Python, and many other languages, *Strings* are ordered *lists* of *chars* and supply the function `__iter__`.

If you pass ['ab'] to set() as in: `set(['ab'])`, the statement is equivalent to `set(list('ab'))` and in this case the iterable is the *list* and not the *string* `'ab'`.

Comment: Good answer. I accepted @S.M.Styvane answer simply because he answered first.

Comment: Nice answer. Would you mind adding an explanation why `set('ab')` is equivalent to `set(['a', 'b'])`? (`set` taking an iterable as argument and stuff...)

Comment: Sure... I just gave that a try... I would appreciate it if you review it! Thx

Comment: don't worry @beni